# Search database with single Search() function, dynamic where

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have a large data set of Persons in a database.  I would like to return a list of people based off a given search parameter.

My dream interface (best to my knowledge) would be.

```
List<People> myList1 = PersonSearch(p => (p.Name = "Tester"));
List<People> myList2 = PersonSearch(p => (p.ID = 123));
```

Performance is a big issue in my case so I don't want to load a giant collection and then filter.  I want my database to only return the results that matter based off my search criteria.

I already have a Person class (not directly tied to my database table) and individual Find() functions.

```
Person person = FindByID(int id);
List<People> people = FindByName(string name);
```

Is there anyway to accomplish the single Search() easily, or will I have to keep my multiple Find() functions?

I asked a similar question yesterday but ended up confusing myself:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608861/lazy-collection-find-with-predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece of information here is there was no use of any ORM (Object-relational mapping) at all.  Connecting to the database using classic ADO.NET objects will not provide the desired functionality and an ORM, such as Entity Framework, must be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your `PersonSearch` function like this:

```
public List<People> PersonSearch(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)
{
    return db.Persons.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

You can even make this work for all your entities:

```
public List<T> Search<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) where T: class
{
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess the part I am missing is where the db object is coming from.

Comment: The 2nd search function should be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` if you want query composition to work.

Comment: I see, I was just looking narrowly at the one thing that stuck out in my mind.

Comment: Yeah, should better get to sleep as my mind is totally clouded lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameter of `Expression` type:

```
public List<People> PersonSearch(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate)
{
    return db.Set<Person>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

It's important, because there is two `Where` extensions - one for in-memory IEnumerable, and another for IQueryable. You should use IQueryable extension which accepts `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to convert filter into SQL and execute it on server side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What object type is db?

Comment: @JaredFeldman its `DbContext`. But you can use `db.Set<Person>().Where(predicate)` directly... Why do you need such method?

Comment: I guess I am lost.  When I copy your code, it has no current context for the DbContext object.  Where is this coming from?  Just create it from my SqlConnection?

Comment: @JaredFeldman ok, lets step back. Do you use some ORM in you project? Or you do all queries manually via ADO.NET?

Comment: This is most likely the giant step I am missing.  ORM is relating my C# Person class to my database table?  If so, I am not.

Comment: @JaredFeldman DbContext is the base class of EntityFramework, most popular ORM in .NET world. So, how is your `FindByID(int id)` and `FindByName(string name)` methods implemented?

Comment: Both are constructing string queries and using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader to read and set my values.

Comment: So you have some custom SQL code, and you want your program to be able to generate exactly same code from expression like `p => p.Id == 42`. That is not possible. But you can use ORM which generates SQL code for you (its not always the best possible SQL, but its good enough)

Comment: Thank you for your help, what ORM would you suggest?  I was just looking at LINQ to SQL.  thoughts?

Comment: @JaredFeldman better go with Entity Framework - its a successor of LINQ to SQL, and its more powerful

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.  I was able to accomplish so much just this morning while experimenting with LINQ to SQL and SqlMetal.  I will look into Entity Framework after the holidays.  Cheers!